# C# - Compare two strings by using dots in the strings and using wildcards: *

Tags: c#, string, split, compare, equality

I have two string variables that i want to compare.

```
var compareA = "something.somethingelse.another.something2"
var compareB = "*.another.something2"
```

I want to compare this, and the result is: **True**.

```
var compareC = "something.somethingelse.*"
```

compared to compareA, the result should also be: **True**.

Of course, the fact that both variables can contain N dots also complicates the task.
How would you start for him?

I was tried this:

```
 static void Main(string[] args)
    {

        var A = CompareString("*.something", "other.Another.something"); //I need this is true!
        var B = CompareString("something.Value.Other.*", "something.Value.Other.SomethingElse"); //I need this is true
        var C = CompareString("something.Value.Other", "something.Value.Other.OtherElse"); //I need this is False
        var D = CompareString("*.somethingElse", "other.another.Value"); //I Need this is false

        Console.WriteLine("It is need True: {0}", A);
        Console.WriteLine("It is need True: {0}", B);
        Console.WriteLine("It is need False: {0}", C);
        Console.WriteLine("It is need False: {0}", D);
}



        private static bool CompareString(string first, string second) 
    {
        var resume = false;
        var firstSplit = first.Split('.');
        var secondSplit = second.Split('.');
        foreach (var firstItem in firstSplit)
        {
            foreach (var secondItem in secondSplit)
            {
                if (firstItem == "*" || secondItem == "*" || string.Equals(firstItem.ToLower(), secondItem.ToLower()))
                {
                    resume = true;
                }
                else
                {
                    resume = false;
                }
            }
        }
        return resume;
    }
```

The results are good, but I think it can be done differently, and the reasoning may be wrong.

Comment: what have you ***tried yourself*** so far? what problems did you encounter? what have you researched? please **edit** your question to include more information. i recommend [taking the tour](https://stackoverflow.com/tour), as well as reading [how to ask a good question](https://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask) and [what's on topic](https://stackoverflow.com/help/on-topic). also: your current description of what should match and what not is quite vague.

Comment: Use Regex maybe?

Comment: So looking at your examples are you basically comparing strings and checking if 1 contains the other, with the addition of wildcards?

Comment: What if compareC was "something.another" and compared with compareA? Should that be true or false?

Comment: @sr28 If compareC is "something.another" the answer is **false**

Comment: @Charlieface I thought about regex, but I couldn’t put it well.

Comment: Something like `new Regex(a.Replace(".", "\.").Replace("*", ".+?")).IsMatch(b)` you need to escape `.` with a backslash `\.` and change `*` wildcard to `.+?`

Comment: @sr28 Yes, but it is definitely wrongly defined that way.
The resume will always reflect the last state. Overwriting the information if something somewhere in the middle doesn’t match.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Assuming the following:

- Compare 1 string to another and it's the full string of 1 contained inside the longer of the 2 strings.
- Case to be ignored as well as culture.
- The full stops are considered part of the string, not actually as a separator.
- Wildcards can be used to state how 1 string can be contained within another.

You should be able to use the following

```
    private bool HasMatch(string textToSearch, string searchText)
    {
        if (textToSearch.Length < searchText.Length) return false;

        var wildCardIndex = searchText.IndexOf('*');

        if (wildCardIndex == -1)
        {
            return textToSearch.Equals(searchText, StringComparison.InvariantCultureIgnoreCase);
        }
        else
        {
            if (wildCardIndex == 0)
            {
                var text = searchText.TrimStart('*');
                return textToSearch.EndsWith(text, StringComparison.InvariantCultureIgnoreCase);
            }
            if (wildCardIndex == (searchText.Length - 1))
            {
                var text = searchText.TrimEnd('*');
                return textToSearch.StartsWith(text, StringComparison.InvariantCultureIgnoreCase);
            }                   
        }

        return false;
    }
```